# connecting to a mesos development cluster on ubuntu 14 machine via opevpn

Tags: mesos, mesosphere

can someone who has successfully settup a mesos development cluster on google cluster help me out.. i have the clutser running however I am having a hard time creating a vpn to conect to the clutser even though I have openvpn installed on my machine and I have downloded the openvpn file provided by mesos. I am using ubuntu 14. basically i have followed instruction to create the cluster but in order to access mesos, marathon I need to configure a vpn connection by using the openvpn file provided by mesosphere but I do not how to do it on ubuntu 14..

Comment: You say you followed the instructions, what errors are you seeing when you try to connect now?

Comment: thank you @EricRenouf. the error that I get is that " the vpn connection failed". i have opened the ".ovpn file I downloaded" and used the info in it ie: ca.cert, certificate, key to configure the vpn connection but it failed

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `openvpn --config <file.ovpn>`?